# Long LaTeX file causes a strange error

Tags: errors, miktex

I have a long LaTeX article (1000 lines, single file) which also has a lot of figures and a few tables.

```
\documentclass[english]{egpubl}
```

%http://www.eg.org/index.php/docs/eg-tutorials/doc_download/14-egpublstyle-cgf

The article compiles with a few warnings. However if I uncomment any of the lines in a paragraph near the end of file, I get an error:

```
! File ended while scanning use of \@writefile
Miktek 2.8 gave \end{document} as location
Miktek 2.9 gives \begin{document} as location
```

The error appears on 3rd build pass (not on the first 2 after cleaning project). The PDF file seems to be generated normally. However this error makes me nervous.

The offending paragraph:

```
To check segmentation expertize of the primary author,
%one dataset (F02) was manually segmented both by the primary author
and a neurosurgeon (the second author).
%Dice coefficient is 91\%, which is on par
%with segmentation correlations between neurosurgeons~\cite{ExpertDSCs} (86-96\% DSC).
```

I am using TeXnicCenter on Win7 x64 with 32-bit MiKTeX.

Should I just ignore this error, or is there a way to fix it?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) for the first Q. A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Comment: What happens if you uncomment just this line: "one dataset (F02) was manually segmented both by the primary author"?

Comment: Uncommenting any of those 3 lines leads to the error, including that one.

Comment: Have you read your .log file? I remember getting really strange errors on the second or third run once. I didn't understand them until I read through the entire .log file. It turned out I had to many figures and the error was actually "too many unprocessed floats" or something like that. You say you have a lot of those, so you might want to check.

Comment: when i see errors like this (i don't think it's specific to miktex) it usually means there's a problem earlier in the file that's incidentally triggered by something happening later on.  does the log say something like "\end occurred inside a group at level 1)"?  if so, keep moving the `\end{document}` back until this disappears, using the "divide and conquer" method to isolate the offending paragraph.  comment that out, and try running the job through to the end; if the job then completes, you know where to look more closely.

Comment: Is this file part of an `\include` or `\input` command? If so, check its encoding. They all need to be the same and match the `\usepackage[e.g. utf8, ansinew, ansi]{inputenc}`. To check the encoding see the status line (bottom right hand side) of TechnixCenter. If the encoding is wrong just press `Save Copy As...` in File Menu and then chose the appropriate one.

Comment: PDF statistics:
 455 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 87 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 196 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)

So I have not reached those maximums.

Comment: The only thing in the log file with "\end" was this: Package atveryend Info: \enddocument detected (standard20110627).

Comment: @Dženan Please refrain from posting status updates in the comments. You can edit your main question so everybody can see your status on the question at one glance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving \end{document} around led me to the offending line. It was some \url{} at the very end of the document. Thanks barbara beeton!

It is very strange that such an inconspicuous paragraph triggered the error.